# IntelliJ IDEA, how to enable preview tool

Tags: android, android-layout, intellij-idea, ide

[image]

Why it's happening ?
How can I enable it ?
**IntelliJ IDEA version: 12.1.6**

---

**PICTURE UPDATED**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you try to enable preview from wrong context? Double click any of your layout and you will see your preview design or xml code. If it xml, you will have tabs Design/Text on the bottom of center column. Just switch it to Design.[image]